# How to open fragment in particular layout in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
public void onClick(View view){
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.loginlayout, 
fragment).commit();
```

}

[In this image sample, I want to replace Linear Layout only with a fraagment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5hgX.jpg)

> This code is not working for me

Comment: What is the error you're getting? that commit() also contains typo in your code : `comit();`, it is `commit();`.

Comment: that is commit(); typing error, but the code is not working to replace linear layout